# how to use Properties for user login with several user accounts on java

Tags: java, if-statement, authentication, properties

I have this:

```
propiedades = new Properties();

try {
  entrada = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
  propiedades.load(entrada);
  Set set =propiedades.stringPropertyNames();
  System.out.println(set);      
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (entrada != null) {
    try {
      entrada.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

So basiclly whats inside "config.properties" is the following thing:

```
admin=admin
user=userpass
user1:userpas1
```

Next up,i have this code:

```
    public  boolean revisarCredenciales(String userName,String password)
  {
    Enumeration<?> e = propiedades.propertyNames();
    while(e.hasMoreElements())
    {
      for (; e.hasMoreElements();) {
        System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        if (e.nextElement().equals(userName) && propiedades.getProperty(userName).equals(password))
        {
          return true;
        }
      }      
    }
    return false;
  }
```

In this block I tried to do a simple if where if the `e.nextElement() equals userName` (`userName` is just a `txUserBox.getText()`) and `propiedades.getProperty(userName).equals(password(txPassword.getPassword())` then it returns a value, can be either `false` or `true`, and the method where it is called will access the program if true.

The problem comes where it always is returns `true` and with this, doesn't matter what I put on the `textboxes` it will log me on..

Answer (score 0):

To quick answer in case somebody has an error like this i fixed this by just doing:

```
    public  boolean revisarCredenciales(String userName,String password,Set<String> setNombres)
  {
    for (String key:setNombres)
    {
      String pass=propiedades.getProperty(key);
      if( userName.equals(key) && pass.equals(password)){
      return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

On the method to review credentials, because it was getting the setNombres from this:

```
   propiedades = new Properties();

try {
  entrada = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
  propiedades.load(entrada);


} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (entrada != null) {
    try {
      entrada.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
setNombres=propiedades.stringPropertyNames();
```

So, when it reviews the credentials it receives first the username from the JTextField, the password and the set of strings.  When u send the JPassword field do new String(txPassword.getPassword()). If you dont do it and send just txPassword.getPassword() it will send the password encripted and cant match then.

```
public  boolean revisarCredenciales(String userName,String password,Set<String> setNombres)
      {
for (key:setNombre(Position))
   { 
     pass(the one written on the textbox)= propiedades.getProperty(key);
                                          //Here it obtaions the value in properties, next to key

if( userName.equals(key) && pass.equals(password)){
 //UserName is what is in the textbox  /pass defined on top.equals(What is on the textbox)

      return true;
    //if that happens returns true, this proccess repeats for each line of the config.properties
      }
    }
return false;
}
```